# Addressable data causing errors on player build

Tags: build, addressables

I've implemented addressables on most data of my project to improve performance, but for some reason even though the application work as expected on the editor, the player build version present errors. I was able to reproduce the same errors happening on build at the editor by changing the "Play mode script" tab from "Asset database (fastest)" to "Use existing build (Windows)", but I don't know where should I go from there.

On editor, everything is assigned correctly (only if the option "Asset database (fastest)" is selected as mentioned), while on build, all data which should be loaded with addressables aren't assigned, causing common errors like NullPointerException and such.

Already tried to change the addressables' build settings too, but it didn't solved my problem either...

Why this happens anyway? I mean, if it's working on editor, it should be the same on build...

Please help me, this is affecting my development, considering I can't run proper tests to see if my changes improved the application's performance.

Basic technical info:

- Target platform: PC
- Unity version: 2021.3.16
- Addressables package: 1.19.19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was happening because I was releasing the asynchronous handle, I thought this was necessary to actually improve my project's efficiency, but this causes the loaded references to be lost at build runtime. The different play modes are pretty misleading on that regard, considering the same code runs well at editor level while does not on build level.

I'm facing another set of issues now, but this one is solved apparently!